# the functionality to update the paypal shipping address?

Tags: paypal

During express checkout via Paypal a shipping address is established and then the user comes back to the checkout page in , if they then change their shipping address that is not being updated back to Paypal. How can the new shipping address can be configured in PayPal by changing shipping address from billing page??

Answer (score 1):

When the user comes back to your site you have that option of displaying a final review page.  It sounds like you're doing that and allowing the user to make changes to the shipping address at this point.  In order to pass that shipping address into the final payment you just need to make sure that address gets included in the DoExpressCheckoutPayment request.

Comment: I have called SetExpressCheckout again before submitting the final order, which should update the new shipping address in PayPal , by setting the parameter ADDROVERRIDE to "1" in the request object.Response is generated for second request and PayPal token is also generated but new address is not getting updated on PayPal site. Do I need to set anyother parameter for same??

Comment: That's not the correct way to handle it.  You don't call SEC twice.  That would effectively create a fresh token for an entirely separate checkout.  What you need to do is call SetExpressCheckout to get the original token just like you already.  Send them over to PayPal, let them review and continue, and then when they get back that's when you call GetExpressCheckoutDetails to pull the address and load it into your review page.  If they need to make an adjustment, let them make it here and simply pass that data into DECP.  Calling SEC here does nothing to effect that original checkout.

Comment: Whatever you pass into the final DoExpressCheckoutPayment request is what's going to get used in the PayPal system.